# error in design matrix: "Design matrix not of full rank. The following coefficients not estimable"

Tags: r, bioconductor

I have a design matrix for my data as below. I run command for analyzing and comparing different groups together but get error.

I would like to have these comparisons: 
    L4vsL6.L8 , 
    Q3vsQ5.Q7, QvsL

design matrix:

`design`

```
                organoids_biological_samples   method
L4_D49_rep_1                              L4      L
L4_D49_rep_2                              L4      L
L6_L8_D49_rep_1                        L6_L8      L
L6_L8_D49_rep_2                        L6_L8      L
Q3_D49_rep_1                              Q3      Q
Q3_D49_rep_2                              Q3      Q
Q5_Q7_D49_rep_1                        Q5_Q7      Q
Q5_Q7_D49_rep_2                        Q5_Q7      Q

design$organoids_biological_samples <- factor(design$organoids_biological_samples, levels = c("L4","L6_L8", "Q3", "Q5_Q7"))

design$method <- factor(design$method, levels = c("L", "Q"))

all(rownames(design) %in% colnames(data))

all(rownames(design) == colnames(data))

Group <- factor(paste(design$organoids_biological_samples,design$method,sep="."))

design<- cbind(design,Group)

design.matrix <- model.matrix(~0+Group+method,design)

colnames(design.matrix) <- c("L4.L", "L6_L8.L", "Q3.Q", "Q5_Q7.Q", "method")
```

`design.matrix`

```
                L4.L  L6_L8.L  Q3.Q  Q5_Q7.Q  method
L4_D49_rep_1       1       0    0       0      0
L4_D49_rep_2       1       0    0       0      0
L6_L8_D49_rep_1    0       1    0       0      0
L6_L8_D49_rep_2    0       1    0       0      0
Q3_D49_rep_1       0       0    1       0      1
Q3_D49_rep_2       0       0    1       0      1
Q5_Q7_D49_rep_1    0       0    0       1      1
Q5_Q7_D49_rep_2    0       0    0       1      1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 1 1 1 1 2
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$Group
[1] "contr.treatment"

attr(,"contrasts")$method
[1] "contr.treatment"

edgeR.dgelist = DGEList(counts = data,group = Group)

edgeR.dgelist = calcNormFactors(edgeR.dgelist,method = "TMM")

CommonDisp <- estimateGLMCommonDisp(edgeR.dgelist, design.matrix)

Error in glmFit.default(y, design = design, dispersion = dispersion, offset = offset,  : 
  Design matrix not of full rank.  The following coefficients not estimable:
 method
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a strict **linear dependency** in your data:
`Q3.Q + Q5_Q7.Q = method`. 
Therefore your model can not find a unique coefficient for these columns
if `B1, B2, B3` is an optimal set of coefficients so is `B1-x, B2-x, B3-x` for any real number `x`.

Numerically your program can not invert the matrix to find the optimal coefficient.
Consider testing if it is better to include both Q3.Q and Q5_Q7.Q or just method in your model.